# Hibernate infinite recursion and bidirectional relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jackson

I have two entities. I want a **bidirectional** relationship between projects and tasks.

- A project has one or more tasks
- A task is associated to only one project

There are my entities:

---

**ProjectEntity.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class ProjectEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "pr_id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "pr_name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="project",orphanRemoval=true)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<TaskEntity> tasks = new HashSet<TaskEntity>();

   // Getters, constructors, setters
```

---

**TaskEntity.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
public class TaskEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ta_id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "ta_name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="pr_id")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private ProjectEntity project;

    // Getters, constructors, setters
```

I would like to have the list of tasks in each `ProjectEntity`, and in each `TaskEntity` the project associated.

Here, I'm using `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` to stop the infinite recursion it generated, but in my `ProjectEntity`, I don't have the tasks list (because of the `@JsonBackReference`) ...

Could you help me to get back tasks list in `ProjectEntity` ? I heard about `@JsonIdentifyInfo`, but I have not managed to do with.

Hope I'm understandable :)

Comment: Here is awesome mini guide with simple examples about your case and how to use @JsonIdentifyInfo  http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Comment: I've seen it before asking my question, it does not resolve my problem ... :/
Thanks anyway

Comment: In that case, why didn't try to make a custom serializer for the Project.tasks collection that write out each task within its associated id's Project (and not only the list of tasks' id)?  Where do you want stop the serialization?

Comment: Can you detail your idea a bit more ? :)

Comment: I write the idea on the answer, maybe you can adapt it to your needs :9

Answer (score 5):

The solution that I know is really using '@JsonIdentityInfo' in instead of '@JsonBackReference' and '@JsonManagedReference'.
You have to remove the '@JsonBackReference' and '@JsonManagedReference' to use '@JsonIdentityInfo'.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class ProjectEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "pr_id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "pr_name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="project",orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<TaskEntity> tasks = new HashSet<TaskEntity>();
}


@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
public class TaskEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ta_id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "ta_name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="pr_id")
    private ProjectEntity project;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could opt for implement a custom serializer for the list ProjectEntity.tasks. But you must controll/stop the serialization cycle at some point; this will depend on your requirements.
Here is an example of what I mean.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class ProjectEntity {
    ...
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="project", orphanRemoval=true)
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomListSerializer.class)
    private Set<TaskEntity> tasks = new HashSet<TaskEntity>();
}
```

And the CustomListSerializer could be something like this,

```
public class CustomListSerializer extends JsonSerializer<List<TaskEntity>>{

    @Override
    public void serialize(List<TaskEntity> tasks, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider)
          throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        generator.writeStartArray();

        for (TaskEntity task : tasks) {
            generator.writeStartObject("taskEntity")
                .write("id", task.id)
                .write("name", task.name)
                .write("project", task.project.id) //<- here you stop the cycle 
            .writeEnd();
        }
        generator.writeEnd();
    }
}
```

Note that it is basically the example of the [mentioned mini guide](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion) but it serialize information of the elements of project's tasks list instead of the tasks' id only.

Comment: `2018-04-13 17:20:57.209  WARN 7340 --- [nio-9090-exec-9] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Cannot override _serializer: had a ´com.project.serializer.SaleItemSerializer´,`

Comment: `trying to set to ´org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$NestedEntitySerializer´; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot override _serializer: had a ´com.project.serializer.SaleItemSerializer´, trying to set to ´org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$NestedEntitySerializer´`

Answer (score 0):

When you use bidirectional relationship need to keep in mind the following:

1. Using entities directly in presentation layer results in Hibernate HttpMessageNotWritableException - using DTO solves this problem - [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36834223/18668094)
2. If you use lombok @Data annotation on the related entities there is Circular dependency issue with the toString() autogenerated method - [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61434519)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).