# Hibernate HttpMessageNotWritableException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am currently using Hibernate 4.3.5 in Spring MVC 4.2.3. I have two model `User` and `Client`, where `id` of `User` is the foreign key of `Client`.

In the `User` class:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

protected SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    try {
        return (SessionFactory) new InitialContext().lookup("SessionFactory");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI", e);
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not locate SessionFactory in JNDI");
    }
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "user")
public Set<Client> getClients() {
    return this.clients;
}

......
}
```

and in `Client`, I set:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
public User getUser() {
    return this.user;
}
```

THe `SessionFactory` is defined in `root-context.xml`. In this way, I should be able to get `clients` from detached `User` object, right? However, when I ran this code:

```
results.addAll(userDAO.findById(id).getClients());
```

it returned the following exception:

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: com.hersbitcloud.cancercloud.models.Client["user"]->com.hersbitcloud.cancercloud.models.User["clientss"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]->com.hersbitcloud.cancercloud.models.Client["user"]->com.hersbitcloud.cancercloud.models.User["clients"]->org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet[0]-
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
```

The stack trace is extremely long, which I think, means when I get the `User`, it fetches `Client` at the same time because it is `EAGER`. Then the `User` Object is fetched again as inner object of `Client`, **even it is set as `LAZY`**. This process go back and froth, never stop.

I understand `LAZY` only fetch stuffs in the session. My question is, why the session to `User` never expired?

Comment: Are you using JSON? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32354856/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-spring-mvc-4-2-and-hibernate-jpa-issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your models (entities) have bidirectional mapping. 
When Jackson tries to serialize objects it faces `user.getClients()[0].getUser().getClients()....` recursive chain. Because you directly use entities on the presentation layer.

You can do few things.

1. Use DTOs
2. Use `@JsonIgnore` on your entity directly (I don't prefer DAO/MVC mixing)
3. May be more options

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325387/infinite-recursion-with-jackson-json-and-hibernate-jpa-issue) has better ways to do it

Comment: It solves the problem, thanks. I think the problem is the Jackson data mapping. It tries to retrieve everything. If using a DTO, everything's fine. BTW, `@JsonIgnore` works fine too.