# Errors Handling Circular References/Dependencies of JPA/Hibernate Entity Bidirectional Relationships with Jackson `JsonIgnoreProperties`

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have been asking something similar in this question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54775257/jpa-bidirectional-relationship-throws-java-lang-stackoverflowerror-null), but the answer did not resolve the problem also i saw a tutorial for handling circular references [here the post](https://hellokoding.com/handling-circular-reference-of-jpa-hibernate-bidirectional-entity-relationships-with-jackson-jsonignoreproperties/),  I applied what they told me but i have the same error. I will leave the code here.

I have two entities Leader and Voter , One Leader has Many Voters and Many Voters have One Leader.

Leader Entity Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "leaders")
public class Leader implements Serializable  {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    String phone;

    @NotEmpty
    String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "leader",  fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("leader")
    private  List<Voter> voters;


    public Leader() {
        voters = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCelular() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setCelular(String celular) {
        this.phone = celular;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.name = nombre;
    }

    public List<Voter> getVoters() {
        return voters;
    }

    public void setVoters(List<Voter> votantes) {
        this.voters = votantes;
    }

    public void addVoter(Voter votante){
        voters.add(votante);
    }
}
```

Voter Entity Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "voters")
public class Voter implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    String id;

    String name;

    String phone;

    String email;

    @Column(name = "electoral_school")
    String electoralSchool;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    Date registrationDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "leader_id")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("voters")
    Leader leader;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)

    Sector sector;

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        registrationDate = new Date();
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getElectoralSchool() {
        return electoralSchool;
    }

    public void setElectoralSchool(String electoralSchool) {
        this.electoralSchool = electoralSchool;
    }

    public Date getRegistrationDate() {
        return registrationDate;
    }

    public void setRegistrationDate(Date registrationDate) {
        this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
    }

    public Leader getLeader() {
        return leader;
    }

    public void setLeader(Leader leader) {
        this.leader = leader;
    }

    public Sector getSector() {
        return sector;
    }

    public void setSector(Sector sector) {
        this.sector = sector;
    }
}
```

LeaderController Class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/leader")
public class LeaderController {

    @Autowired
    ILeaderService leaderService;

    @RequestMapping(value="test")
    public @ResponseBody List<Voter> getAll(){
        return leaderService.findById(1L).getVoters();

    }

}
```

VoterController Class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/voter")
public class VoterController {

    @Autowired
    IVoterService voterService;

    @RequestMapping(value="test")
    public @ResponseBody List<Voter> getAll(){

        return voterService.findAll();

    }
}
```

Here are the errors when i consult a `http://localhost:8080/voter/test`:

2 errors

## 1

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:472) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.sendServerError(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:549) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.handleHttpMessageNotWritable(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:439) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveException(DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.java:209) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:139) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:80) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1297) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1109) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.16.jar:9.0.16]
```

## 2

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:737) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:719) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:155) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:727) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar:2.9.8]
```

How i can solve this and have a Simple API Rest working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When `JPA` bi-directional serialize to json, it will be infinite because of `bi-directional`. That's why you should you `@JsonIgnore` in one site.

Comment: Yes as you say, the problem is That I use the annotation @JsonIgnoreProperties() for avoid the infinity loop but doesn't work for me, I still have the error.

Comment: can you share github url for source code if possible, will give a try and raise merge request. including DB schema SQL.

Comment: ForRef: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa

Answer (score 1):

**@JsonIgnoreProperties** ignores the specified logical properties in JSON serialization and deserialization.

> It is annotated at class level.

The logical property "*voters*" has been specified in **@JsonIgnoreProperties** annotation.So these logical properties will not take part in JSON serialization and deserialization.
It means the union of logical properties ignored by **@JsonIgnore** and **@JsonIgnoreProperties** are considered to be ignored in JSON serialization and deserialization.

**Voter Entity class**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "voters")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("voters")  <- HERE
    public class Voter implements Serializable {

    ...given code

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "leader_id")
    @JsonProperty("voters")  <- HERE
    Leader leader;

    ...given code
```

I've made some changes in your given code, Hope this may work in your given code.